# DocuSign : Using Conditional Field with Optional Signature

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

We are working on an application where the end user needs to do embedded DocuSign. The document contains an optional signature tab and a custom tab text-box. We need to make text-box visible only if the end user has signed using "SignHereOptional" tab. for this we are using conditional fields.

Below is the code we are using for our application. But somehow we are not able to achieve the desired result.

```
Tab parent = new Tab();
parent.DocumentID = "1";
parent.RecipientID = "1";
parent.PageNumber = "1";
parent.Type = TabTypeCode.SignHereOptional;
parent.CustomTabTypeSpecified = true;
parent.XPosition = "100";
parent.YPosition = "200";
parent.TabLabel = "CustomerSign";

Tab child = new Tab();
child.DocumentID = "1";
child.RecipientID = "1";
child.PageNumber = "1";
child.Type = TabTypeCode.Custom;
child.CustomTabType = CustomTabType.Text;
child.CustomTabTypeSpecified = true;
child.ConditionalParentLabel = "CustomerSign";
child.ConditionalParentValue = "Signed";
child.XPosition = "300";
child.YPosition = "400";
```

Please let us know if there is any work around for this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your logic look like for checking the value of the parent tab?  For optional signature tab types you need to check against the value **"on"**.

The REST API Guide has the following description for *ConditionalParentValue*:

```
Optional element. For conditional fields this is the Value of the parent tab that controls this tab’s visibility.

If the parent tab is a Checkbox, Radio button, Optional Signature, or Optional Initial use “on” as the value to show that the parent tab is active.
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me. I just changed the value to child.ConditionalParentValue = "on".